# Are conditional probabilities only work on uniform distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, intuition

The conditional probability of $A$ given $B$ is defined by $\mathrm{Pr}(A\mid B)=\mathrm{Pr}(A\cap B)/\mathrm{Pr}(B)$. I'm trying to understand this intuitively, but the intuition only works for the uniform distribution sample space, so I'm suspicious that there're conditional probabilites for not uniform spaces. Maybe my concepts are very restricted since I'm a beginner in probability theory. If so, what are the examples?

Answer (score 1):

There's a typo in the formula: the numerator should be the probability of intersection. Intuitively, you are "reducing" your space to $B$ ($B$ is now your whole space, if you condition it), hence the probability of $A$ know $B$ happened is the probability of $A$ (inside $B$, that is the intersection) divided by the probability (or the "size") of your new whole space, which is $B$,

Comment: Yeah I found out myself that I can think it as the reduced sample space $B$ which is $B\subset \Omega$. But what I'm asking is that the definition of $\mathrm{Pr}(A\mid B)$ seems like it's only for a uniform distribution, because the 'reduced sample space' is in the denominator.

Comment: In fact, I don't even know if there are other models that is not uniform. And I'm thinking it's because my concept is restricted somehow.

Comment: Furthermore, apparently, I think the conditional probability is not even an actual probability, because it doesn't satisfy the probability axioms.

Comment: It satisfies the probability axioms, so it is a probability itself. I think I can understand you when saying is a uniform model... but I think that the non-uniformity is encoded in the fact that $Pr$ may not be uniform (that is, when dividing by $Pr(B)$ you are performing a uniform model if you regard $Pr(B)$ as some kind of "size", but this "size" may not be uniform). Also, maybe this is the only (intuitive) defnition that keeps the probability axioms satisfied.

Comment: As you know, probability function $\mathrm{Pr}$ is a funtion from the sample space $\Sigma$ to real numbers $\mathbb{R}$, i.e., $\mathrm{Pr}:\Sigma\to\mathbb{R}$. Its domain members must be the form of an event, but the conditional probability has a differnt form, $A\mid B$. Even if I let the parameter as a pair $(A,B)$, it's still not a member of the event space. Hence it can't even possible to put this term in the axioms.

Comment: The events are not of the form $A|B$, this is just a notation: the function for the conditional probability is defined for a given set $B \in \Sigma$:
$\Pr(\cdot | B) \colon \Sigma \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $A \mapsto \Pr(A|B)$. This satisfies the axioms and is indeed a probability.